# Regular expression : Get a number after a matching word in php

Tags: php, regex

Fetch Bill no from a string (output from tesseract OCR)

Tesseract OCR string is as follows

```
1;FTC013233

259139 Bill Date 23/06/2015
Mrs. DR.Greesshma-â€˜H Age/sex 23;y 22;D 1 Fema|e

Bill No 34939
Hospital ' Req No HG-4 1142645

3;HASH'KA'-A- D 9 %

  Eergncy

VH)

a.. . !â€˜:â€˜u"â€˜_â€˜i"

Total Amount:

Paid Amount :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` along with `Positive Lookbehind` regex as

```
preg_match('/(?<=Bill\sNo\s)(\d+)\b/',$str,$res);
echo $res[0];//34939
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
/Bill\s+No\s+(\d+)/ig
```

**[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/wW7gD9/2)**

**PHP CODE :**

```
<?php
$re = "/Bill\\s+No\\s+(\\d+)/i"; 
$str = "1;FTC013233\n\n259139 Bill Date 23/06/2015\nMrs. DR.Greesshma-â€˜H Age/sex 23;y 22;D 1 Fema|e\n\nBill No 34939\nHospital ' Req No HG-4 1142645\n\n3;HASH'KA'-A- D 9 %\n\n  Eergncy\n\nVH)\n\na.. . !â€˜:â€˜u\"â€˜_â€˜i\"\n\nTotal Amount:\n\nPaid Amount :1;FTC013233\n\n259139 Bill Date 23/06/2015\nMrs. DR.Greesshma-â€˜H Age/sex 23;y 22;D 1 Fema|e\n\nBill No 34930999\nHospital ' Req No HG-4 1142645\n\n3;HASH'KA'-A- D 9 %\n\n  Eergncy\n\nVH)\n\na.. . !â€˜:â€˜u\"â€˜_â€˜i\"\n\nTotal Amount:\n\nPaid Amount :"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Why to use `i` modifier over here

Comment: to match `bill no` , `Bill no` or `bill No`